# What was a blind man lamenting about ? Of course about his eyes

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I am looking for an equivalent idiom or expression in English. In my native language this idiom is used when somebody makes, I would say, an unnecessary statement (to emphasize the obvious fact ) in relation to the existing situation. For instance - you crashed your car and after the accident one of your friends says : you need to get it fixed. So, you reply - that is what I`m talking about ! What was a blind man was complaining about ?...

Comment: And what native language might that be?

Answer (score 4):

## [No shit, Sherlock](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no_shit,_Sherlock)

> An expression of amazement followed by comparing the [interlocutor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interlocutor) to the detective Sherlock Holmes, as if they have just made a great deduction. This expression is, however, used sarcastically, to point out that the interlocutor merely stated the obvious.

Answer (score 3):

[**You think?**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=you%20think%3F)

> a sarcastic reply to someone who utters a statement that is obvious or that goes without saying.

Answer (score 3):

You could say "Thanks, Captain Obvious!"

> Thanks Captain obvious is the appropriate response to someone who says something blatantly obvious. This can be said kindly and in jest to one’s friends or spitefully to the jerk that’s been irritating you.
>   <sub>[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Thanks%20Captain%20Obvious)</sub>

This expression is pretty common. You can find plenty of memes that use it such as the following:

- [Spiderman](https://esmemes.com/i/thank-you-captain-obvious-none-13216826)
- [Animated Gif](https://tenor.com/view/captain-obvious-thank-you-superhero-gif-9900289)
- [Cat](http://wallpaperen.com/thanks-captain-obvious-meme/cool-thanks-captain-obvious-meme-thank-you-captain-obvious-meme-memes/)
- [Deadpool](https://www.flickr.com/photos/82779236@N05/9522747653)
- [Hotels.com Captan Obvious](https://memegenerator.net/instance/67332435/thanks-captain-obv-thanks-captain-obvious)
- [Rotund Captan America](http://whisper.sh/whisper/0544c29eb282cb214e2142a2dc20a7a35d1fdf/Gee-thanks-Captain-Obvious)

Comment: In my family, the person thanking Captain Obvious is Lieutenant Sarcasm

Answer (score 2):

The expression **duh!**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/duh)

> Used to express disdain for something deemed stupid or obvious,
>   especially a self-evident remark.

Answer (score 1):

## [**No Kidding!**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/no+kidding)

> 2. Inf. Everyone already knows that! Did you just find that out? (Sarcastic.) Sue: It looks like taxes will be increasing. Tom: No kidding! What do you expect? Alice: I'm afraid I'm putting on a little weight. Jane: No kidding!